# How do I use StyledComponents in the Next.js 13 app folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

From the [Next.js docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/css-in-js):

> Warning: CSS-in-JS libraries which require runtime JavaScript are not
> currently supported in Server Components.
>
> The following libraries are supported in Client Components in the app
> directory:
>
> - styled-jsx
> - styled-components
> - style9

**Questions**

1. Does that mean I have to use the `use-client` directive in every component that uses *StyledComponents*?
2. If so, is it possible to write all *StyledComponents* in one file, with the `use-client` directive at top, and then just import these *Client Components* as needed into the *Server Components*?
3. Will the approach above somehow turn the *Server Components* into *Client Components*?
4. The Next.js docs state that all components within the `app` directory are *Server Components* by default. If we save a component outside the `app` directory and import it into a *Server Component* in the `app` directory, will that imported function then also become a *Server Component*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer your questions.

1. Yes you have to use it every time you use StyledComponents.
2. It is possible but Next.js will render it as Client Component even though you import it inside a Server Component.
3. From the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components), it will make the component into Client Component if the page that you're trying to render are all components with 'use client' directive. Next.js will render it server side if there are any Server Component inside the page and send the rest to the client.
4. Yes it will become server components as long as the components that are imported isn't using the 'use client' directive.

Hope it helps.